# I would like to prove the following series: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\frac{\sin{\frac{\pi}{n}}}{n}}\cdot(x-2)^n $ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, convergence-divergence

I would like to prove the following series: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\frac{\sin{\frac{\pi}{n}}}{n}}\cdot(x-2)^n $$ is convergent (absolutely?) or divergent.
Now I know that it converges for: $|{x-2}|<1$, but I am having trouble proving it. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The coefficient  $\frac{\sin(\pi/n)}{n}$ has absolute value less than $1$. So comparison with the geometric series gives convergence.

Comment: @AndréNicolas That doesn't work for finding the radius of convergence of the power series.

Comment: The sequence has to converge to zero which is obviously not the case if $| x-2 |>1$

Comment: @WillFisher: It tells us we have convergence if $|x-2|\lt 1$. True, we need more to show divergence for $|x-2|\gt 1$, and a finer estimate still to deal with the two endpoints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this we want to apply the ratio test to find the radius of convergence. So what we have is
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left|\frac{\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)}{n+1}(x-2)^{n+1}}{\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)}{n}(x-2)^{n}}\right|<1$$
Which simplifies immediately to
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left|\frac{n\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)(x-2)}{(n+1)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)}\right|<1$$
Then we know that as $n\to \infty$, we have $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)=\frac{\pi}{n}$. This is because the inside of the sine function approaches zero, and for small $x$, $\sin(x)\approx x$. So then what we have is
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left|\frac{n\left(\frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)(x-2)}{(n+1)\frac{\pi}{n}}\right|<1$$
Which we then simplify down to
$$\left|\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}\right|\cdot |x-2|=|x-2|<1$$
Which leaves us with the fact that the series converges when $x \in (1,3)$, and now all thats left is to test the endpoints. For $x=1$ we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})}{n}(-1)^n$$
which converges by the alternating series test. And for $x=3$ we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})}{n}\le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\pi}{n^2}$$
which converges by the comparison test. So we find that the interval of convergence is $x\in [1,3]$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $0 \le \sin (\pi/n)\le \pi/n.$

Answer (score 0):

$$\left|\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})}{n}(x-2)^n\right|<\left|(x-2)^n\right|$$

The geometric series $\; \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(x-2)^n}\;$converges as you already found out for $|x-2|<1\;$ Hence your series converges (by applying Weierstrass M-Test).